# Menu not responding to media queries on iPhone?

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, jquery-ui, responsive-design

Bit confused here. I have a webpage set up at http://www.fraserboag.com/test as I've been developing a simple responsive menu with some jQuery.

In my CSS, I have one breakpoint at 800px, which will change the display of the menu to a toggleable slide-out menu. This works perfectly in a desktop browser which is resized to below 800px wide, however when I load this page on my iphone it just shows the standard menu. Even if I zoom in, the nav just breaks onto more lines and starts obscuring content.

What am I missing here? I'm new to writing this kind of responsive menu by hand having been used to bootstrap and such in the past so I assume I'm just overlooking some small detail.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in a viewport meta tag like this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, totally overlooked that!